# How to create a generic bash shell that will run whatever python is in the PATH?

Tags: python, bash, shell

Due to a complex corporate setup and having a venv I use in the CI pipelines and in the target deployment, I need the python inside my venv bin to run whatever python is in the PATH. I do the following but seems to end in an infinite loop:

This is the content of my $DEPLOYMENT_VENV/bin/python

```
#!bin/bash
python $@
```

the default actual python to use is setup in the PATH before.

Why would this lead to infinite loop or hanging forever?

Comment: Is `$DEPLOYMENT_VENV` the name of a virtual environment? You should not muck with the files inside the virtual environment at all. If it is correctly set up, `$DEPLOYMENT_VENV/bin/python` will be a wrapper or symlink which runs the correct Python version for this virtual environment. Individual Python scripts should be executable and have `#!/usr/bin/env python3` or possibly `#!/usr/bin/env python` in their shebang line or just be run with `python scriptname.py`

Comment: As an aside, `$@` is wrong; you want to quote it `"$@"`.

Comment: @tripleee this is exactly the problem ... by doing what's being explained in the OP I ensure having only one `$DEPLOYMENT_VENV/bin/python`  i.e. without having to change it in each different environment it runs. Then shift the problem of finding the right python to the environment variables or initialization before using the venv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an infinite loop if the `python` found by bash is the same than `$DEPLOYMENT_VENV/bin/python`.

There could be several reasons: the `PATH` variable does not have the same value in your terminal, than in the environment where the script is executed, etc.

To troubleshoot this, you should modify temporary the `$DEPLOYMENT_VENV/bin/python`, in order to add 2 lines to generate extra debug log message in a temporary file `/tmp/dbg-python.txt`:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "DBG: " >>/tmp/dbg-python.txt 2>&1
type python >>/tmp/dbg-python.txt 2>&1
printf "\nDBG: PATH=%s\n" "${PATH}" >>/tmp/dbg-python.txt 2>&1
# python $@
```

Test again.

What is the content of the `/tmp/dbg-python.txt` file?

Comment: This was exactly the issue. Placing in `PATH` the python executable I care about first then it works.